# How does a phone detect charge on its USB port if there is already 5 V on it?

Tags: batteries, usb, routing

I am trying to design a device that charges a battery through a USB port and can communicate through it and give power through the same port. I didn't find any solution on how to detect when it is charging so I stop the current from a DC/DCB converter and supply current to charge a battery.

Comment: Welcome! How are you handling the USB handshake and power negotiation?

Comment: Hi winny, I didn't know nothing about this, so you gave me a path to follow,... embarasing but helpfull, thanks. Do you recommend me any resource to learn about it?

Comment: So google "usb handshake and power negotiation"...

Comment: usb.org has all those specifications https://usb.org/sites/default/files/D2T2-1%20-%20USB%20Power%20Delivery.pdf